# Set default shell to MacPorts bash in Mac OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: terminal, bash, macports

As a follow up to my [previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69936/terminal-and-bash-cant-start-with-libiconv-error), I reinstalled my MacPorts and want to try its newer version of bash again.

I installed the newest bash via MacPorts on my Mac OS X 10.6.8 system, but when I start a Terminal.app session, the "sh --version" command showed I was still using the old bash 3.2.48. This is even when "which bash" points to the newer 4.2.37 installed by MacPorts.

I tried to change Terminal.app preferences to use the new bash as default, changed /etc/shells, and used the chsh command to specify MacPorts bash as the default. However, none of these methods were successful. What am I missing? Thank you very much.

Comment: So you broke the shell once already, and you want to see how to do it again?  The reason `which bash` shows the newer shell but you're running the older one is that the shell is launched by absolute path (/bin/bash) and doesn't obey the path.  Which wouldn't matter anyway, since the path isn't set to include MacPorts until .bashrc is run.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`sh --version` is probably the same as `/bin/sh --version`. If the current shell is bash, you can see its version with `echo $BASH_VERSION`. If you change the default login shell with chsh, you can keep Terminal's default shell as the login shell.

1. `sudo port install bash`
2. Add `/opt/local/bin/bash` to `/etc/shells`
3. `chsh -s /opt/local/bin/bash`
4. Open a new tab and check `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: @VictorSergienko No it does not echo $SHELL shows what shelll you have set as the default login shell